# Antd InputNumber deletes decimal digits after comma

Tags: reactjs, regex, typescript, input, antd

I'm trying to have an InputNumber component in a form.
It should format the number I write like this 1.234,56 (with any number of digits before the comma and max 2 decimal digits after the separator).

I have [Antd InputNumber formatter documentation](https://ant.design/components/input-number/#components-input-number-demo-formatter) right here and I copied the `formatter` and `parser` props from there, changing ',' with '.'

For the digits before the comma, it works right. If I write 1111111 the input renders 1.111.111, but if I put something after a comma, to have a decimal number, when I click outside the input box, it deletes those digits.
If I write 1234,56 it renders 1.234,56 and then it turns it into 1.234.

This is my code:

```
<InputNumber 
   prefix="€" 
   style={{ width: "100%" }} 
   decimalSeparator={","}
   formatter={value => `${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')}   // |(?=(,\d{0,2}))
   parser={value => `${value}`.replace(/(\.*)|/g, '')}   // |(,?)
/>
```

I've never used regexes before so I tried adding the ones in the comments right next to formatter and parser, but that did't change anything.

Do i miss something? Does Ant have something like `thousandSeparator` from react-number-format or the only way to do it is using formatter? I can't seem to find anything about this problem